# Response Header for illegal file (format)

Tags: http, http-response

I have a simple upload-servlet and need to report if a file is illegal and has not been added.

For some reason i am not allowed to give a html-body back, so i need to use the response-header.

Unfortunately the `X-`-response-headers [should not be used anymore.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6648) So what response-header match my requirements? I daresay `Warning` may match best, but when the file is not added, its more likly a *error* than a *warning*.

Comment: BTW: I also am not allowed to give a different HTTP-Status-Code back.

Comment: How about just returning a custom 4xx error? Or even a 400 Bad Request one, if you want to keep things as simple as possible?

Comment: @YannisRizos 1. A upload can contain multiple files. 2. A apache is before the tomcat who proxy only 200-responses, otherwise a i8nzed error-file from apache is returned.

Comment: Hm, if uploading multiple files won't block just because there's one illegal file, then isn't your response more of a warning (thus `Warning` is semantically accurate) than an error?

Comment: A illegal file is anyway a error! You can not open a .exe as a image. You can not open a .jpg as an audio-file. You can not rotate a .txt by 12 degrees.... Always you will get an Error.

Comment: Well yes, but you code's task is to upload the files, not open them. That task, according to your previous comments, doesn't fail when one of the files is invalid. Thus, returning a warning makes sense. Although, I must say what I'd do is throw a 4xx and just ignore all uploaded files if one of them was invalid.

Comment: Yes, 415 and `Warning` sounds good. Maybe there is a better code than `Warning` i dont know.